# Nestjs roles guard invokes 2 times and gets user undefined at first

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nestjs-passport

I use passport and want to protect few routes by roles.
It looks like guard invokes 2 times. At first it logs user undefined. Second time it logs user correct. What I did wrong? See screenshots of implementation.

[image: roles guard]

[image: app module]

[image: usage]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first time that the guard runs comes from the globally bound guard

```js
{
  provide: APP_GUARD,
  useClass: RolesGuard
}
```

As this is a global guard, it will be the first guard invoked in the request chain (and because there are no other guards). Your `RolesGuard` is looking at the `req.user` property, which gets assigned by `passport`. In NestJS this is ususally done by the `AuthGuard` which will call `passport.authenticate()` under the hood. The code there is a bit complex, so trust me on it for now.

Due to how you have your guards bound, as mentioned, the execution looks like `RolesGuard (global)`, `JwtAuthGuard (route level)`, `RolesGuard (route level)`. That second route level guard, your second `RolesGuard` runs *after* the `JwtAuthGuard` so it has access to `req.user` as you would expect it to.

Now, the next question you'll probably ask is "How can I fix this?" What I've done for this in the past is I've bound my `JwtAuthGuard` (or similar) global and ran it before the `RolesGuard`, but added in a check for metadata on if the route should be authorization protected or not. Using decorators we can add metadata to classes and route handlers (kind of what Nest is about being able to do in the first place) and read it from the guard thanks to the `ExecutionContext` in the `canActivate` method. You can inject Nest's `Reflector` into the guard class as well and make a check like `this.reflector.getAllAndMerge<boolean>('SHOULD_SKIP_AUTH', [context.getHandler(), context.getClass()])`. Theoretically, this would return a boolean that you've set via the decorator on the class or route handler level, if it returns `true` (i.e. you should skip the auth) then the request guard could short out to a `return true` and let the request move on its own.

Comment: What about removing RolesGuard from app.module? I did that and included only on route level. Effect still the same.

Comment: If you remove the global guard then it should call the guards in the correct order. [The request lifecycle is documented here](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle)

Comment: Now it looks like this:
`@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGO_HOSTNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}/${process.env.MONGO_DB}`),
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
    FilesModule,
    DevelopersModule,
    MulterModule.register({
      dest: './public/images',
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService
  ],
})`
I still get 2 invocations.

Comment: This is app.module ofc

Comment: Without a reproduction or full access to your code, I won't be able to say why. Don't forget to rebuild your application.

Comment: Feel free to check it out https://github.com/AdKamil/nestjs-auth-problem.git 
P.S. Branch "feature/files-upload-multiple-save-to-db"

Comment: Your `UserModule` still have the `APP_GUARD` provider. That is a **global** provider, you can register it in any module and it applies **globally**

Comment: Thank You. Everything is fine. App is definitely work in a proper way.
One more problem still remains.
What is Your address, because I'd like to send You a truck fully loaded in beer? ;-)